# If $R$ is a commutative simple ring with identity , then is any matrix ring $M_n(R)$ also simple?

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

If $R$ is a commutative simple ring with identity , then is any matrix ring $M_n(R)$ over $R$  of matrices of size $n$ also simple ?

Comment: Ye.  There's a bijection between their double sided ideals.

Comment: Commutativity of $R$ is not required. By the way, a simple commutative ring (with unity) is a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two-sided ideals of a matrix ring $M_n(R)$, regardless of what kind of ring $R$ is, are all of the form
$$M_n(\mathfrak A)$$
for some two-sided ideal $\mathfrak A\subset R$. Hence, $M_n(R)$ is simple iff $R$ is.